# How to load multiple bmp files in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple bmp files named :

Frame 1.bmp, Frame 2.bmp, Frame 3.bmp, Frame 4.bmp....

How can I load them by creating an array of numbers spanning the frame number and use a for loop iterating over the range?

I knew that how to load a single bmp file:

```
from PIL import Image
frame_1 = Image.open('downloads/ Frame 1.bmp')
frame_1_bw = frame_1.convert(mode="L")
```

but I have trouble with loading multiple files.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use simple loop:

```
from PIL import Image
frames = []
for i in range(1, 10): # 10 is number of frames + 1.
    frame_1 = Image.open(f'downloads/ Frame {i}.bmp')
    frame_1_bw = frame_1.convert(mode="L")
    frames.append(frame_1) # save frames for later use
    # .... do something else with frame_1
# use loaded frames list
```

Answer (score 1):

Arty's solution is good, but if your files aren't numerically named I suggest placing your images in a folder and then getting all the files from that folder, then load them via a for loop.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from PIL import Image

mypath = './downloads/'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

for img_file_path in onlyfiles: 
    frame_1 = Image.open(f'{mypath}{img_file_path}')
    frame_1_bw = frame_1.convert(mode="L")
```